# Как убрать просвет между изображениями в FireFox на canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Есть канвас, на нём есть таблица с изображениями которые плотно прилягают к друг другу, в хроме (изображение без горизонтальных линий) - просвет не виден, всё хорошо, а в фаерфоксе он есть (изображение с горизонтальными линиями)

Не подскажете рецепт как этот дефект в фаерфоксе убрать в канвасе?

[image: Изображение с линиями]

[image: Изображение без линий]

Comment: Не могу понять что на прилагающейся картинке НЕ дефект, поэтому отвечу наугад. Вам стоит попробовать использовать только целочисленные координаты и по возможности размеры изображений должны быть кратны степени двойки, ну или хотя бы при их создании закладывалась хоть какая-то математическая основа, чтобы соблюсти первый пункт. Ещё на ум приходит сглаживание и параметры которые определяют порядок пикселей, но это уже сложно ответить вот просто так.

Comment: Горизонтальная линия, на одной картинки она есть (дефект), на другой отсутствует(НЕ дефект). Там ведь всего одна горизонтальная линия, спасибо попробую)